# Jenkins session vs. Console

Tags: python, django, jenkins, virtualenv, jenkins-plugins

Can't get my build environment running and running crazy.

This is might connected to environment vars or other settings.

- OS is Ubuntu 14.04
- Jenkins 1.601

The same venv with the same user works perfect on console.

Virtualenv Builder Script:

```
pip install -r $WORKSPACE/backend/requirments.txt
$PYTHON_EXE $WORKSPACE/backend/server/manage.py jenkins
```

Output:

```
File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_unused_import_py30.py", line 10
Compiling /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_unused_import_py30.py ...
    class Meta(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_used_before_assignment_py30.py ...
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_used_before_assignment_py30.py", line 10
    nonlocal cnt
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Compiling /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_w0705.py ...
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/func_w0705.py", line 28
    __revision__ += 1
SyntaxError: default 'except:' must be last

Compiling /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/build/pylint/pylint/test/input/syntax_error.py ...
Sorry: IndentationError: expected an indented block (syntax_error.py, line 2)
Successfully installed Django Markdown PyJWT PyYAML Werkzeug astroid django-cors-headers django-extensions django-filter django-guardian django-jenkins djangorestframework djangorestframework-jwt flake8 logilab-common mccabe pep8 pyaml pyflakes pylint six
Cleaning up...
+ /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/bin/python /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Shiftly_Backend/workspace/backend/server/manage.py jenkins
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Shiftly_Backend/workspace/backend/server/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jenkins/management/commands/jenkins.py", line 105, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jenkins/runner.py", line 132, in setup_databases
    return super(CITestSuiteRunner, self).setup_databases()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 109, in setup_databases
    return setup_databases(self.verbosity, self.interactive, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 299, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST_SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/creation.py", line 374, in create_test_db
    test_flush=True,
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 128, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 297, in sync_apps
    call_command('loaddata', 'initial_data', verbosity=self.verbosity, database=connection.alias, skip_validation=True, app_label=app_label, hide_empty=True)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 61, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 79, in loaddata
    self.serialization_formats = serializers.get_public_serializer_formats()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 110, in get_public_serializer_formats
    _load_serializers()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 152, in _load_serializers
    register_serializer(format, BUILTIN_SERIALIZERS[format], serializers)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 70, in register_serializer
    module = importlib.import_module(serializer_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/shiningpanda/jobs/44bf933c/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/xml_serializer.py", line 15, in <module>
    from xml.sax.expatreader import ExpatParser as _ExpatParser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise SAXReaderNotAvailable("expat not supported", None)
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXReaderNotAvailable: expat not supported
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python version problem. It seems like your code is in Python 3 syntax, whereas your server has Python 2 installed.

Comment: With Python 3 dose the pip process not complete. The Project is python 2 due to some libs and runs perfect on a console. The test is executed with python 2.7.6

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. That code is Python 3, and simply will not work on Python 2.

Comment: That code is Python 2! and runs on a regular console perfect with Python 2.7.6

Comment: This code: `class Meta(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):` is not valid in Python 2, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe you are running python 2 code with a python 2 interpreter you might need to unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```